# Add a delay to a React-Admin logout process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I've implemented a AuthProvider.js in my React-Admin application and I'd like to delay the logout process by, say 5 seconds, and during that time period show a modal that says "logging out...".

For context, here's the example from the [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AuthProviderWriting.html#example):

```
logout: () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('username');
    return Promise.resolve();
},
```

I've set my AuthProvider.js to delay the logout process by seconds with following code:

```
logout: () => {

    // [add code here to show a modal]

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {

            localStorage.removeItem('username');

            // [add code here to hide the modal]

            resolve();
        }, 5000); // add a delay of 5 seconds
    });
},
```

Is there any way to show the user a modal of some kind during the delay (see "add code here" comments)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add some state like this

make a custom hook

```
// useModal.js

import { useState } from 'react';

const useModal = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const showModal = () => {
    setIsVisible(true);
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    setIsVisible(false);
  };

  return { isVisible, showModal, hideModal };
};

export default useModal;
```

then

```
// AuthProvider.js

import React from 'react';
import useModal from './useModal'; // Import the custom hook

const AuthProvider = {
  // Other methods...
  const { isVisible: isLoggingOut, showModal, hideModal } = useModal();

  logout: () => {

    showModal(); // Show the modal when logout is initiated

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        localStorage.removeItem('username');
        hideModal(); // Hide the modal after the delay
        resolve();
      }, 5000); // add a delay of 5 seconds
    });
  },
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

then create a modal component that is conditionally rendered based on the value of isLoggingOut.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I get this error: "Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons..." I'm not sure why. The syntax is different from most js code I'm used to. Object literal syntax maybe?

Comment: @Woodchuck what if using custom hook? move the state and the function showModal() and hideModal() to custom hook then call it inside the logout function I guess

Comment: i try to edit my answer. hope it help

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I still get the error: "Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component ..."

Comment: @Firofa I’ve edited your code. Accept the edit.

Comment: @Chukwujiobi Canon, if I follow correctly, your edit was to move the const for the useModal outside of the logout. That gives another, different error: "Unexpected keyword 'const'."

Comment: Ohh I see… `AuthProvider` is an object not a Stateless Functional Component.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement communication between AuthProvider and React Component. You can do this with closure. for example:

```
function buildAuthProvider({ onLogoutStarted, onLogoutFinished }) {
  return {
   ...
   logout: () => {
      onLogoutStarted(); //dispatch event to react component
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
        onLogoutFinished(); //dispatch event to react component
       }, 5000); // add a delay of 5 seconds
     });
   }
  }
}
```

then in your React component

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Admin
     authProvider={
      buildAuthProvider({
        onLogoutStarted: () => {
          //tell react component to show logout modal
          //for example you can use Redux dispatch function
        },
        onLogoutFinished: () => {
          //tell react component to close logout modal
          //for example you can use Redux dispatch function
        } 
      })
     }
     dataProvider={dataProvider}
    >
    </Admin>
  );
 }
```

you can use redux to dispatch event into your React component

Comment: React-admin v4 no longer uses Redux. This approach is probably outdated.

Comment: @slax57 you dont have to use Redux, the point is you need to implement communication between react-admin component and caller component. In authProvider creation you need to supply callback function inside logout function. The callback function has responsibility to tell caller that logout function has been executed